# Javascript Regex to digit/decimal and minus sign

Tags: javascript, regex

In my web form textbox, I want to allow only numerical value with  only 2 digit after decimal and there can negative (minus) sign before the digit. For example xxx.xx or -xxx.xx OR xxx OR -xxx . I know following code will do almost my requirement but how should I allow only -(minus) sign before digit?

```
onBlur="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');"
```

So whatever user types, alpha characters and other symbols should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.value.replace(/^(-?).*?(\d+\.\d{2}).*$/, "$1$2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove any minus signs that is not the first character, after you have removed the other characters:

```
onBlur = "this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.-]/g, '').replace(/(.)-+/g, '$1');"
```

Comment: @user3344151: Hm... Could you be more specific?